# Changing legend position using Visreg package in R

Tags: r, graph, model, legend, legend-properties

I'm using Visreg to visualize a negative binomial general linear model with interaction terms. The problem I'm running into is that when using overlay=TRUE the legend noting which lines correspond to which level of the "by" variable is placed on top of the graph, directly over the title. I've tried a weird workaround by adding returns to the end of the title, but I find when I re-size the graph to be larger the legend is pushed up until it is completely hidden.

My code:

```
visreg(fit, "med.income.2010.scale", by="hs.edu.2010", overlay=TRUE, 
partial=FALSE, scale="response", 
   main="Inspection Rates by Income and Education",
   ylab="Predicted Routine Inspections",
   xlab="Median Household Income (thousands)",
   strip.names=c("10th Percentile", "50th Percentile", "90th Percentile"),
   legend=TRUE)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: can we have  a reproducible example please ... ?

Comment: Thank you for the interest Ben, I actually ended up finding a workaround by assigning the visreg output to an object, (v=visreg(fit, etc...)) plotting that with r's basic plot function (plot(v, etc...), and using the legend function following it.

Comment: please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a workaround by assigning the visreg output to an object, (v=visreg(fit, etc...)) 
plotting that with r's basic plot function (plot(v, etc...), and using the legend function following it.

My full code is

```
'v= visreg(m1.routine.inspect, "med.income.2010.scale", by="hs.edu.2010", overlay=TRUE, partial=FALSE, scale="response", legend=FALSE)'

plot(v, overlay=TRUE, legend=FALSE,
 main="Inspection Rates by Income and Education,\nInteraction Term Excluded",
 ylab="Predicted Routine Inspections per well",
 xlab="Median Household Income (thousands)",
 font.lab=1,
 yaxs="i",
 ylim=c(0,1.1),
 cex.lab=1)

legend.enhanced("bottomright", 
   c("10th Percentile", "50th Percentile", "90th Percentile"),
   lty=1,
   lwd=3,
   col=c("red", "forestgreen", "royalblue"),
   bty="n",
   title=expression(underline("HS Grad Rate")),
   horiz=FALSE,
   y.intersp=.5,
   x.intersp=.5,
   title.adj=c(.5,0),
   title.col="black",
   seg.len =1,
   cex=1,
   yjust=.3,
   text.font = NULL,
   inset = .05
   )
```

Normally you would just use legend(....), but a user had posted a modified function that allowed for better adjustment of the legend title.